# Is there an application that can record video the process on the screen of the android phone?

Tags: android, video-capture

I created an application for android. Now, I want to record a video on how to use the application. Is there an application that can record video the process on the screen of the android phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 5-6fps is good enough for you, there's DroidEx. [Check this out.](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/951-how-to-capture-video-of-the-screen-on-android/)